# How to check the length of service that return an array and map this value as a pipe line?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, pipeline, ngrx

I have this pipe line but in this point, is not efficient because is causing not reachable code  in order to dispatch the action, I am thinking on a tap. What is the better way to integrate the action in a pipeline?

```
 map((myStore) => {
    return myStore.getUsers().map(({name, lastName}) => {
       return {
         name: name,
         sureName: lastName
       }            
     });

     if (myStore.getUsers().length === 0) {
         this.store.dispatch(new saveNameAction('James', 'Smith'));
     }
 })
 .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the subscribe itself:

Something like this:

```
map((myStore) => {
    return myStore.getUsers().map(({name, lastName}) => {
       return {
         name: name,
         sureName: lastName
       }            
     });
 })
 .subscribe(myModifiedStore => {
   console.log(myModifiedStore.getUsers());
   if (myModifiedStore.getUsers().length === 0) {
      this.store.dispatch(new saveNameAction('James', 'Smith'));
   }
 });
```